# ( | vs. || ) "OR" Operator Comparison in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I understand that in C/C++, the `||` is the normal OR comparison operator, and that `|` is the bitwise OR operator.
My question is, why do we have 2 different operators for the same thing? Why don't we just use `|` everywhere?

---

Example:

```
int n = 1;
if (n == 1 | n == 2) { cout << "Condition Matched\n"; }
```

[image: screenshot]

This also works, because conditions on either side of the `|` operator, ie: `(n == 1)` and `(n == 2)` are evaluated as boolean / single-bit values anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: `1 | 2` is 3. `1 || 2` is `true`. `1 || (2/0)` is `true`. `1 | (2/0)` is undefined.

Comment: not always the result of the operator is converted to `bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the more important differences is that the `||` operator short-circuits, but the `|` operator doesn't.  Consider:

```
void f(int* p)
{
    if (!p || *p == 0) 
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

If we used the `|` operator here and p was `nullptr`, we would end up dereferencing a null pointer.  The `||` operator prevents this by short-circuiting the evaluation.